# SubscriptionClient.RecieveBatch not retrieving all the brokered messages

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a console application to read all the brokered messages present in the subscription on the Azure Service Bus. I have around 3500 messages in there. This is my code to read the messages:

```
SubscriptionClient client = messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topic, subscription);   
long count = namespaceManager.GetSubscription(topic, subscription).MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount;
Console.WriteLine("Total messages to process : {0}", count.ToString()); //Here the number is showing correctly
IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> dlIE = null;
dlIE = client.ReceiveBatch(Convert.ToInt32(count));
```

When I execute the code, in the dlIE, I can see only 256 messages. I have also tried giving the prefetch count like this `client.PrefetchCount`but then also it returns 256 messages only.

I think there is some limit to the number of messages that can be retrieved at a time.However there is no such thing mentioned on the msdn page for the `RecieveBatch` method. What can I do to retrieve all messages at a time?

**Note:**

1. I only want to read the message and then let it exist on the service bus. Therefore I do not use `message.complete` method.
2. I cannot remove and re-create the topic/subscription from the Service Bus.

**Edit:**

I used PeekBatch instead of ReceiveBatch like this:

```
    IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> dlIE = null;
                            List<BrokeredMessage> bmList = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
  long i = 0;
   dlIE = subsciptionClient.PeekBatch(Convert.ToInt32(count)); // count is the total number of messages in the subscription.
  bmList.AddRange(dlIE);
  i = dlIE.Count();
 if(i < count)
  {           
 while(i < count)
  {
  IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> dlTemp = null;
   dlTemp = subsciptionClient.PeekBatch(i, Convert.ToInt32(count));
    bmList.AddRange(dlTemp);
    i = i + dlTemp.Count();
    }
    }
```

I have **3255** messages in the subscription. When the first time peekBatch is called it gets 250 messages. so it goes into the while loop with `PeekBatch(250,3225)`. Every time 250 messages are only received. The final total messages I am having in the output list is **3500** with duplicates. I am not able to understand how this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out. The subscription client remembers the last batch it retrieved and when called again, retrieves the next batch.

So the code would be :

```
    IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> dlIE = null;
List<BrokeredMessage> bmList = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
  long i = 0;  
  while (i < count)
  {
   dlIE = subsciptionClient.PeekBatch(Convert.ToInt32(count));
   bmList.AddRange(dlIE);
   i = i + dlIE.Count();
  }
```

**Thanks to MikeWo for guidance**

**Note:** There seems to be some kind of a size limit on the number of messages you can peek at a time. I tried with different subscriptions and the number of messages fetched were different for each.

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer. "By using the same SubscriptionClient with PeekBatch under the hood the last pulled sequence number is kept as as you loop through it should keep track and go through the whole queue."

Comment: @MikeWo sorry I didn't read your answer here but for some other question in SO. Actually before I saw your answer here I was working with peekbatch based on your answer somewhere else.

Comment: @MikeWo Is there a limit to the number of messages retrieved by PeekBatch ?? It works fine for 3200 but when there are 5000 messages on the subscription, it shows this error : Internal Server Error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a premature session shutdown.

Comment: @MikeWo I think there is some topic issue. Because even giving peekbatch(250) in that gives the same error. the subscription with 3200 messages(which worked) was in another topic.

Comment: In theory no maximum is mentioned in the docs that I could find, and the messageCount parameter is an Int; however, I don't think I'd ever count on being able to grab really large groups at once like that. For peeking it's likely not that bad, but it depends on how big they are, consistency in size and what you are doing with them in general. As for the error, like you said that could be something else and not a problem with the message count.

Comment: @MikeWo I think its not the message count but the total size of the batch received. Because for some subscriptions I am able to retrieve 250 at a time and for some only 100. The message sizes are different for different subscriptions in my case.

Comment: Which makes sense to me. As I mentioned before, getting that many messages at once, even while peeking, seems like it's not a good idea depending on why you are getting them to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Is the topic you are writing to partitioned by chance? When you receive messages from a partitioned entity it will only fetch from one of the partitions at a time. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn520246.aspx):

*"When a client wants to receive a message from a partitioned queue, or from a subscription of a partitioned topic, Service Bus queries all fragments for messages, then returns the first message that is returned from any of the messaging stores to the receiver. Service Bus caches the other messages and returns them when it receives additional receive requests. A receiving client is not aware of the partitioning; the client-facing behavior of a partitioned queue or topic (for example, read, complete, defer, deadletter, prefetching) is identical to the behavior of a regular entity."*

It's probably not a good idea to assume that even with a non partitioned entity that you'd get all messages in one go with really either the Receive or Peek methods. It would be much more efficient to loop through the messages in much smaller batches, especially if your message have any decent size to them or are indeterminate in size.

Since you don't actually want to remove the message from the queue I'd suggest using [PeekBatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj908734.aspx) instead of ReceiveBatch. This lets you get a copy of the message and doesn't lock it. I'd highly suggest a loop using the same SubscriptionClient in conjunction with PeekBatch. By using the same SubscriptionClient with PeekBatch under the hood the last pulled sequence number is kept as as you loop through it should keep track and go through the whole queue. This would essentially let you read through the entire queue.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I was using the PeekBatch approach and have some issue with it. I have updated the question. Can you please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue where `client.ReceiveBatchAsync(....)` would not retrieve any data from the subscription in the azure service bus.

After some digging around I found out that there is a bit for each subscriber to enable batch operations. This can only be enabled through powershell. Below is the command I used:

```
$subObject = Get-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription -ResourceGroup '#resourceName' -NamespaceName '#namespaceName' -Topic '#topicName' -SubscriptionName '#subscriptionName' 
$subObject.EnableBatchedOperations = $True

Set-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription -ResourceGroup '#resourceName' -NamespaceName '#namespaceName' -Topic '#topicName'-SubscriptionObj $subObject
```

More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/Set-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription?view=azurermps-4.3.1). While it still didn't load all the messages at least it started to clear the queue. As far as I'm aware, the batch size parameter is only there as a suggestion to the service bus but not a rule.

Hope it helps!